# Button won't stay inside the div I put it in, ejs

Tags: html, ejs

I'm using ejs templates for my webpage, and I'm having layout troubles.
I have a button inside a `<div>` that's set to display:none as a dropdown, and should show up when the container is hovered over. Instead, the buttons that should be in the dropdown are rendered outside of it and have seemingly no relation to it.
Source ejs file:

```html
<button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised dropdown" id="clear">
    Clear
    <div class="mdc-card dropdown-content">
        <p>Test</p>
        <button>TestButton</button>
    </div>
</button>
```

And the resulting page according to chrome's element viewer:

```html
<button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised dropdown" id="clear">
    Clear
    <div class="mdc-card dropdown-content">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</button>
<button>TestButton</button>
```

The `<p>` tag still displays correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can put a `button` element within a `button` element.

Try it out on MDN here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

This is the example input I put into their live editor. When you inspect the button, you'll get the same output as you've shared in your post.

```
<button class="favorite styled"
        type="button">
  <button>Hello</button>
    Add to favorites
</button>
```

Depending on where you need the button, you could try styling the outside or inside element to look like a button as a work around!

Comment: It seems buttons won't go in other buttons, so I've opted to just use `<p>` tags ans style them up a bit